# Anything wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, labview

I'm using LabVIEW and the Database Toolkit to execute an SQL query, and it keeps barfing on this for syntax reasons. I'm using MySQL through the ODBC connector. Each line should have a newline character at the end except for the last.

The error LabVIEW is throwing is this:

Possible reason(s):

> ADO Error: 0x80040E14 Exception
>   occured in Microsoft OLE DB Provider
>   for ODBC Drivers: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1
>   Driver][mysqld-5.1.42-community]You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'UPDATE
>   plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00'
>   WHERE Address = '1092'; UPDATE plc_a'
>   at line 2 in
>   NI_Database_API.lvlib:Conn
>   Execute.vi->UpdatePLCAddressesTable.vi->DevelopSQL.vi

```
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1132';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1092';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1103';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1105';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1161';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1167';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1129';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1088';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1098';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1099';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1100';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1117';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1118';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1106';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1107';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1108';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1109';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1110';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1111';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1151';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1154';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1157';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '-1023.75' WHERE Address = '1119';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '-1023.75' WHERE Address = '1120';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1165';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1095';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1164';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1096';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1097';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1121';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1122';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1123';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1124';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1089';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1101';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1112';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1113';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1114';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1115';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1116';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1091';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1141';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1142';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1143';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1139';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1153';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1148';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1145';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1150';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1147';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1149';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1146';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1104';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1093';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1125';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1126';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1127';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1094';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '0.00' WHERE Address = '1114';
UPDATE plc_addresses SET CurrValue = '-2522.00' WHERE Address = '1114';
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to send these as individual SQL statements, instead of all of them at once.

Comment: +1 There is no where in there that is telling the server that you are running multiple queries in one. It either needs to be consolidated into one query, or it needs to be separated into multiple update queries.

Comment: Yeah, same thing with JDBC.  It is possible to run multiple statements simultaneously in JDBC, but you add them individually to a batch, and then run the batch.  I assume there's a similar feature in ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

ADO does not support multiple statements to be executed in a single operation, you will need to execute them sequentially one after the other. Given they are all similar you might want to use [Prepared Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905910%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. The exception being given complains about the second statement in the batch.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mimer Validator](http://developer.mimer.se/validator/parser200x/index.tml), your SQL is fine. My guess is that for some reason, it doesn't like the semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Enable FLAG_MULTI_STATEMENTS

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html