# Why does the recordset returned by this query have a status of "closed"?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado, labview

I'm running the following SQL query from LabVIEW, a graphical programming language, using the built in capabilities it has for database connectivity:

```
DECLARE @currentID int
SET @currentID = (SELECT MIN(ExperimentID) FROM Jobs_t WHERE JobStatus = 'ToRun');
UPDATE [dbo].[Jobs_t]
SET [JobStatus] = 'Pending'
WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID;
SELECT @currentID AS result
```

[image]

This is the analogous code to main() is a C-like language. The first block, which has the "Connection Information" wire going into it, opens a .udl file and creates an ADO.NET _Connection reference, which is later used to invoke methods for the query.

[image]

This is the inside of the second block, the one with "EXE" and the pink wire going into it. The boxes with the gray border operate much like "switch" statements. The wire going into the "?" terminal on these boxes determines which case gets executed. The yellow boxes with white rectangels dropping down are invoke nodes and property nodes; they accept a reference to an object and allow you to invoke methods and read/write properties of that object. You can see the _Recordset object here as well.

[image]

Here's the next block to be executed, the one whose icon reads "FETCH ALL". We see that the first thing to execute on the far left grabs some properties of the recordset, and returns them in a "struct" (the pink wire that goes into the box that reads "state"). This is where the code fails. The recordset opened in the previous VI (virtual instrument) has a status of "closed", and the purple variant (seen under "Read all the data available") comes back empty.

The rest of the code is fairly irrelevant, as it's just converting the received variant into usable data, and freeing the recordset reference opened previously.

My question is, why would the status from the query of the recordset be "closed"? I realize that recordsets are "closed" when the query returns no rows, but executing that query in SSMS returns rows. Also, executing the LabVIEW code does the UPDATE in the query, so I know that's not broken either.

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask questions about things in LabVIEW; I have no trouble giving you as much information as you need to make a proper assessment.

Comment: I guess from the code sample at top you should see anywhere between 1 and 3 recordsets. The last `SELECT` line in your code should return one record even if `@currentid` is null. Have you tried adding a semi colon to the end? Have you manged to execute multi statement SQL before? what happens if you run this SQL in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: As I said in the last couple paragraphs, execution in SSMS works as expected. The LabVIEW code also works for the most part; the update works right, it's just that final select that doesn't work. I've tried everything, semicolon/no semicolon, go/no go, even throwing in bogus rows to the select to make for certain that wasn't the reason for the closed status. So far, no dice.

Comment: I'm sorry I skipped through your explanation a bit too quickly. You say it returns "rows"... do you mean "row"? There's only one select in there and it will return exactly one row. Not being pedantic its just that I can't see what you see. I don't know how Labviews SQL interface works but have you just tried `SELECT 1 as column1;` on its own to see if that recordset is also closed? then work your way back to your original query. Do you have other similar queries that do work?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean rows! I've added a SELECT 1 to ensure the query returns a row, but haven't done it on its own. I'll be sure to try it as soon as I've got access to my workstation.

Comment: If you did mean row**s**... that doesn't make sense as that code block only returns one row.

Comment: I didnt* must have autocorrected.

Comment: Got an answer! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on the LabVIEW subreddit, and it turns out the database connectivity VIs aren't very good with batch queries. I switched over to using methods and properties of the OdbcConnection, OdbcCommand, and OdbcDatareader classes to achieve what I wanted. Here's the code if you're interested: [image: http://i.imgur.com/fmDymyu.png]

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you to write a stored procedure for this. Secondly, are your [drivers (ODBC)](https://lavag.org/topic/11596-execute-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-call/) up to date? Thirdly, I think you might get better help by posting your question at forums.ni.com or lavag.org. Finally, maybe this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150990/anything-wrong-with-this-sql-query) has an answer which would help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the driver issue. That poster is probably right; my server doesn't like multiple statements. I've tried posting this on forums.ni.com, with no hits (which is weird, considering I got almost 100 views). I'll have to check out lavag, looks promising.